# Probit Hypothesis Test: $H_0: \beta_1 \geq 1$

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, generalized-linear-model, probit

### Problem

Given the output of a ***`probit`*** model and no knowledge of the sample data:

```
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -1.47410    0.31000  -4.755 1.98e-06 ***
x            0.69841    0.16143   4.327 1.51e-05 ***
I(x^2)       0.33622    0.06357   5.289 1.23e-07 ***

    Null deviance: 135.531  on 98  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  51.537  on 96  degrees of freedom
AIC: 57.537
```

At $\alpha=5\%$, test the hypothesis that $\beta_1$ for the probit model is less than $1$.

### Attempt

${\tt H_0}$: $\beta_1 \geq 1$

${\tt H_A}$: $\beta_1 < 1$

I believe I should calculate the $Z_{obs} = \frac{\hat{\beta_1}-1}{ese(\hat{\beta_1})}$ and then find the p-value of $1-\phi(Z_{obs})$, but I'm not sure how to do that. This is what I've got so far (in `R`):

```
alpha <- 0.05
beta1 <- 0.69841
beta1.ese <- 0.16143
z.obs <- (beta1 - 1)/beta1.ese
p.value <- 1 - pnorm(z.obs)
```

The resulting `p.value` $= 0.9691357$. If that's correct, I should fail to reject ${\tt H_0}$ and conclude that $\beta_1$ is not less than $1$.

Am I on the right track, or way off base?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Because it's so easy to get an entirely wrong answer with a mere typographical error or sign change in your calculations, it's always a good idea to use basic concepts at the outset to make a reasonable guess at the answer. For instance, your reasoning seems to go something like this: "The estimate of $\beta_1$ is around $0.7,$ which is $0.3$ less than $1,$ or around two standard errors away from $1.$" So far, so good. But in your experience, what kinds of p-values do differences of two SEs tend to produce? This reasoning suggests how to check your work.

Comment: BTW, there may be some ambiguity in the statements of the hypotheses: I'm unsure what this question really means by "test the hypothesis that $\beta_1 \lt 1.$"  Ordinarily, I would take this to mean that the *null* hypothesis is $\beta_1 \lt 1,$ but you have formulated this as the alternate hypothesis.  Are you sure that was the intention in this question?

Comment: @whuber Yeah, my professor words his questions weirdly, but I'm fairly certain ${\tt H_0}: \beta_1 \geq 1$ is correct. However, `pnorm(z.obs)` ($0.03086431$) would make more sense as a p-value than `1-pnorm(z.obs)` ($0.9691357$). At least, in my experience, p-values don't tend to be that close to $1$.

Comment: @whuber Regardless of whether the null and alternative hypotheses are correct (or should be swapped), is my approach to obtaining a p-value for the test accurate?